# Python - Access one part of a named tuple inside a two-dimensional list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, namedtuple

In Python, I have row data that I'm trying to set to a pandas data frame. However the cell data is a named tuple so my output data contains:

```
Cell(r=1,c=2,v='value').
```

All I want is the v from the named tuple. How would I go about setting my dataframe with only the cell value.

This is what I use to set the rows to the dataframe:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(data=cells)
```

Named tuple and example code below:

```
import collections
Cell = collections.namedtuple('Cell',['r','c','v'])
cells = [[Cell(1,3,5),Cell(6,233,22)],[Cell(6,88,22),Cell(6454,2344443,34)]]
```

Desired result:

```
5   22
22  34
```

Comment: Can you provide some example code for us to reproduce your dataframe, or a portion of it?

Comment: Cell = c.namedtuple('Cell',['r','c','v']) 
cells = [Cell(1,3,5),Cell(6,233,22)] - just one row 

This works: def values(rlist):
    return [item.v for item in rlist]

but obviously i'm using rows and cols so for something like this is what I need:

cells = [[Cell(1,3,5),Cell(6,233,22)],[Cell(6,88,22),Cell(6454,2344443,34)]]

Comment: What is `c`? Please also review how to format your code in your questions: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: c is collections - I'm just reviewing now (this is my first post)

Comment: what is `sh`? Do you have a list of `Cell`s and want to turn each element in the cell into a column?  Or do you have a two-dimensional list and you want to only capture the `.v` part of each named tuple?

Comment: I have corrected the code. Apologies for how poor the post is. it's a two-dimensional list of 'Cell' named tuples. I want a two-dimensional array but only with the .v part of the named tuple.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and congrats on your first Question! Editing until it makes sense to people trying to help, is exactly the right way to go! :+1:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought someone posted an answer here...

```
df.applymap(lambda x: x.v)
```

Basically, accessing the value for `v` in `Cell`.

Edit: This was @JohnE's solution; not sure what the etiquette is here? It would have taken me a little while to get there.

Comment: Feel free to put it back... I'm not familiar enough with pandas to have those solutions ready to go. Much obliged for your patience with the new folks :)

Comment: No worries, this is fine.  Etiquette is case by case.  I just didn't want to jump in if others were working on it.  Especially when you and others had prompted the OP to refine his question up to the point where it could be easily answered.  ;-)

Comment: That's great! Thanks all. I've not had time to really get to grips with Python so I appreciate the help. I struggled to really articulate this question as you probably saw so if I have repeated another question then I'm happy to link to it.